# Angular-fullstack get posted article ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

I'm using angular-fullstack on my project.

```
$scope.saveArticle = function(article) {
   Article.insert({
     //post stuff
   }, function() {
    //get the posted article ID
    $location.path('/blog/ARTICLE_ID');
   });
```

How can I get the just posted article ID?

Comment: Can't you use `article`?

Comment: removed jquery tag since jquery is not related here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$scope.saveArticle = function(article) {
    Article.insert({
        //post stuff
    }, function (response) {
        $location.path('/blog/' + response._id);
    })
};
```

How does that work?

The `_id` would be the name of the ID column in your database. If your ID column has a different name (e.g. ID, tableId, etc.) then change it accordingly.